# Getting column names from df and querying df

Tags: r

When I do:

```
var = names(df)[2]

df$var
```

I get `NULL`. I think that var is a string inside quotes and that is why this is happening. How could get the columns in a dataframe and dynamically query them?

It has been suggested that I use df[var], but what if my dataframe has another dataframe within it? df[var][x] or df[var]$x won't work.

Comment: If you have an unusual data frame with a data frame in it then please show how to construct this in your question.

Comment: A dataframe with "another dataframe in it" is malformed and should be fixed. Unlike lists, dataframes are not designed to be recursive beyond the first level. That is the canonical reason for not using POSIXlt "vectors" (which are really a particular form of list) in dataframes.

Comment: there must be a canonical duplicate for this question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a column of a data frame or item in a list by value of a variable by doing:

```
df[[var]]
```

Comment: double bracket worked for my double dataframe situation as df[[var]]$x!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what error-inducing situation has been constructed without dput-output on the offending dataframe. It's modestly difficult to get a column name as described (with actual quotes in the column name, but its possible. First we can try and fail to get such a beast:

```
df2 <- data.frame("\"col1\""=1:10)
df2[["\"col1\""]]
#NULL
df2
#    the data.frame function coerced it to a valid column name with no quotes
   X.col1.
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        6
7        7
8        8
9        9
10      10
```

So we can bypass the validity checks. Now we need escapes preceding the quotes:

```
df2 <- data.frame("\"col1\""=1:10, check.names=FALSE)
> df2[["\"col1\""]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If the `df[[var]]$x` approach worked for you, then the answer is more likely that `df` is not a dataframe but rather is an ordinary R named list and that it is `x` that is a dataframe. You should check this by doing:

```
str(df)
```

You could make such a structure very simply with:

```
> df3 <- list( item=data.frame(x=1:10, check.names=FALSE))
> var1 = "item"
> df3[[var1]]$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
>  str(df3)
List of 1
 $ item:'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ x: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```